# Using sp_send_dbmail to multiple recipients

Tags: sql, sp-send-dbmail

I have write the following in order to send  to each customers (from the query) an email. how can I solve it
from the

```
SELECT Distinct (CUSTVENDAC) AS 'td','',
            Email AS 'td','',
            TTL_ITEMID AS 'td','',
            TTL_TRANSREFID AS 'td'
FROM PARTS_RIN1
```

I have 4 fields and I would like to send an e-mail to each `CUSTVENDAC` describing that he has the following `TTL_ITEMID` and `TTL_TRANSREFID`.

```
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(max)
SET @email = ''

SELECT @email = RTRIM(@email) + RTRIM(email) + ';'
FROM PARTS_RIN1
PRINT @email

DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT 
Distinct (CUSTVENDAC) AS 'td','',
            Email AS 'td','',
            TTL_ITEMID AS 'td','',
            TTL_TRANSREFID AS 'td'
FROM PARTS_RIN1             
WHERE email= @email
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

SET @body ='<html><body><H2>Order Info</H2>
<table border = 2> 
<tr>
<th> CUSTVENDAC </th> <th> Email </th> <th> TTL_ITEMID</th>
<th> TTL_TRANSREFID </th> 
</tr>'    

SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>'

BEGIN

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = N'sp_send_dbmail', 
      @body = @body, 
      @body_format = 'HTML',
      @recipients = @email,
      @subject = 'Order Results'

END
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on column, it works on the whole selected row. select distinct (c1), c2 eq. select distinct c1, c2 eq select distinct c1, (c2)...

Comment: I have add the distinct in order to get distinct values for the 'CUSTVENDAC' otherwise I had multiple . the problem is not the distinct but the method to take each email according to specific CUSTVENDAC and sent  it

Comment: But you know the whole rows are considered? You can remove the parenthesis around CUSTVENDAC to make it clearer!

Comment: OK. τthe main problem is what I have to change in the code in order to send each email to each customer (CUSTVENDAC) with a desc

Comment: And if one customer has several rows, with different Email, TTL_ITEMID and TTL_TRANSREFID values?

Comment: I have created before a table in order to put all the items and transrefid to one line for each customer so i can solved it.imagine the final table is like this ( there are about 70 different customers)
CUSTVENDAC       Email                TTL_ITEMID  TTL_TRANSREFID 
3000004          ats@net.com   New ItemID: [ HD-90106MBN670 ] New ItemID: [ HD-90106MM9000}        New TRANSREFID: [ SO00457424 ] New TRANSREFID: [ SO00457424 ] 

so if i can send for customer (3000004 ) to his email (ats@net.com ) describing that he has the following TTL_ITEMID and  TTL_TRANSREFID